# Prevent postback in ie8 on dojo button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dojo

I have the following code in my asp.net page:

```
<button dojotype="dijit.form.Button">
    <asp:Label ID="lblClear" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblClearResource1" />
        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
            return ClearCheckBoxes('<%=clientIds.ClientID%>');
        </script>
</button>
```

Where ClearCheckBoxes is the following:

```
function ClearCheckBoxes(obj1) {
    var chks = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        if (chks[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (chks[i].checked == true) chks[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(obj1).value = "";
    document.getElementById('<%=clientsIds.ClientID %>').value = "";

    return false;
}
```

This code works fine in all browsers, except in IE8, which causes a postback. Is there a way to disable a postback in IE8 in this scenario? Everything I've found online said return false; should work but that doesn't prevent the postback.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the default `type` for a button is `submit`, which will end up submitting a surrounding form if one exists.  If this button is not intended to be submitting the form, adding `type="button"` to the `<button>` tag will stop it from behaving like a submit button.

Reduced example: (try removing `type="button"` to see the difference in IE8)

```
<form>
    <button type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Button
        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
            this.set('label', 'Clicked');
        </script>
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `dojo/_base/event#stop`; [here's the documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/event.html#stop), emphasis mine:

> prevents propagation and **clobbers the default action** of the passed event

You can include that in your code.

```
require(['dojo/_base/event']);
```

---

```
<button dojotype="dijit.form.Button">
    <asp:Label ID="lblClear" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblClearResource1" />
        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
                dojo.stopEvent(evt); // dojo/_base/event extends dojo pre-2.0 
                return ClearCheckBoxes('<%=clientIds.ClientID%>');
        </script>
</button>
```

`dojo/_base/event#stop` works cross-browser, including (I believe) in IE8.

In case it's not feasible to `require` modules like that for your templates (I've never done anything like that myself), here's the code specific to preventing default behavior in IE:

```
evt = evt || window.event;
evt.cancelBubble = true;
on._preventDefault.call(evt);
```

Comment: `event.stop` simply calls  `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` on the event.  It is preferred that you call one or the other (or both) as necessary.  In this case, `preventDefault` alone should be enough, though I also suspect that setting the button's type to `button` may avoid the problem outright.

Comment: It doesn't simply call `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation`; the code for the IE-specific portion of `event.stop` is provided above. However, just calling both would probably work with this particular example. The method I gave would be the dojo way to do it, which is what I think this question was going after.

Comment: Dojo normalizes events' `stopPropagation` and `preventDefaults` for old IE so that this logic already happens when you call those functions themselves (e.g. https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/on.js#L446-L449).  `dojo/_base/event` will no longer be a thing in Dojo 2.0 and calling `preventDefault` and/or `stopPropagation` *will* be the way to prevent default behavior or stop events from bubbling, Dojo or not.